# Why does my SQL query not have any columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I'm not an expert by any means but I write SQL queries fairly regularly.

I am pulling data via Crystal Reports 2013 from SQL Server 2016 (not positive about the version). Just as an aside, CR permits parameters so that's what `{?DateStart}` is. `{?DateStart}` and `{?DateEnd}` are regular dates, `{?ServiceProvider}` is a number array. The `EXEC sw_vwDateRange` generates a table that has a row for every date in between `{?DateStart}` and `{?DateEnd}`.

I had this query that worked:
(Edited 2021-01-19 14:28 EST to simplify/improve query)

```
DECLARE @Result Table (CurrentDateTime datetime)

INSERT @Result EXEC sp_vwDateRange {?DateStart}, {?DateEnd}
SELECT * FROM @Result
    
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT Count(DISTINCT ClientID) AS "Clients",
    Count(DISTINCT RoomID) AS "RoomCount"
FROM vw_Stays 
WHERE vw_Stays.BedDateStart <= DATEADD(day,1,CurrentDateTime)
    AND (vw_Stays.BedDateEnd IS NULL OR vw_Stays.BedDateEnd > DATEADD(day,1,CurrentDateTime)) 
    AND vw_Stays.OrganizationID IN {?ServiceProvider}
) t2
```

I was getting some inefficiencies because I was pulling data from a non-indexed view, vw_Stays, so I replaced it with references to the original tables.

```
DECLARE @Result Table (CurrentDateTime datetime)

INSERT @Result EXEC sp_vwDateRange {?DateStart}, {?DateEnd}
SELECT * FROM @Result
    
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT Count(DISTINCT HIFIS_Client_Services.ClientID) AS "Clients",
    Count(DISTINCT HIFIS_StaysRoomsBedsHistory.RoomID) AS "RoomCount"
FROM HIFIS_Stays
    INNER JOIN HIFIS_Services ON HIFIS_Stays.ServiceID = HIFIS_Services.ServiceID
    INNER JOIN HIFIS_Client_Services ON HIFIS_Services.ServiceID = HIFIS_Client_Services.ServiceID
    INNER JOIN HIFIS_StaysRoomsBedsHistory ON HIFIS_Stays.StayID = HIFIS_StaysRoomsBedsHistory.StayID
    
WHERE HIFIS_StaysRoomsBedsHistory.BedDateStart <= DATEADD(day,1,CurrentDateTime) 
    AND (HIFIS_StaysRoomsBedsHistory.BedDateEnd IS NULL OR HIFIS_StaysRoomsBedsHistory.BedDateEnd > DATEADD(day,1,CurrentDateTime)) 
    AND HIFIS_Services.OrganizationID IN {?ServiceProvider}
) t2
```

But it stopped working entirely. It doesn't give me any errors, it just completes the query with no columns and no data.

Sorry if this has already been answered but I really don't know what search terminology to use!

Comment: *"But it stopped working entirely. It doesn't give me any errors, it just completes the query with no columns and no data."* The only reason no columns would be returned is if the batch fails prior to the `SELECT`. If the `SELECT` runs, it'll return an empty dataset; even if it errors (such as a divide by zero). If you're getting no datasets then the batch must be errorring; unless you have logic you aren't telling us about.

Comment: maybe `sp_vwDateRange ` returns no data ?

Comment: FYI, `sp_` is a reserved prefix for **S**pecial **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for user objects (unless you're planning to make it a system object).

Comment: Also check out [This link](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) Naming stored procedure starting with `sp_` could cause serious problems

Comment: @Larnu, that is a helpful piece of information ("batch fails prior to SELECT"), THANK YOU!

Comment: Everybody else, I didn't create the SP, it's a database I did not create, and I have read the reference materials on how to reference it, so my syntax should be good. I have examples of other queries that use the same syntax and they work fine. But thanks for helping me identify the problem area!

Comment: Those two subqueries can be combined with `CROSS APPLY` and if you have `STRING_AGG` you can combine in the third one also. That will speed it up massively. The view itself is not usually slower than the base tables for the same filters and joins.

Comment: @Charlieface, I don't have STRING_AGG, unfortunately. So I guess maybe I have SQL Server 2012? But I didn't know about CROSS APPLY, I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: @Charlieface, `CROSS APPLY` is magic and you are my hero :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, so, this is embarrassing, but turns out I spelled the name of one of the tables wrong. (wrong number of s's in HIFIS_StaysRoomsBedsHistory.) I'll just go crawl away and hide now. But I learned a lot in troubleshooting this! Thanks for the info about `CROSS APPLY`, I will put that to good use.

Answer (score 0):

If you're NOT getting an error on the query itself, only two things would return no records in Crystal.

1. The record selection/filter (which includes parameters) are filtering to return no data. Note, this can also be caused by Crystal passing a parameter differently than you're expecting to get it in the query.
2. SQL Security itself is filtering based on the level of access of user (Windows ID or SQL ID)

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not getting 0 RECORDS. I'm getting 0 COLUMNS. So I think it's a different thing than I've just filtered to exclude all data.

Comment: You said it didn't give you any errors. If a query returns 0 columns to Crystal Reports, you WILL get an error.